# Automatically scan first page with scanimage in batch mode

Tags: shell, command-line, scanner

I'm using `scanimage --batch-prompt` command to scan multiple documents one by one. That way it will ask to confirm scan for each page including first one.

Problem is, my usual use case is to launch that command when I've already placed first page in scanner and I want it to be processed without pressing any keys. Is it possible to use batch mode in a way that will automatically scan first page but then will wait for user confirmation for all others?

Comment: does `scanim(){ (echo; cat)|scanimage --batch-prompt;}`  do what you want?

Comment: @LjmDullaart It does works, thank you. Could you explain what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanimage` does not have such an option.

With a simple `bash` function, you can provide the first `enter` with an `echo` and wait for the other enters with `cat`. That is what

```
echo;cat
```

does.  You can test this with:

```
(echo;cat)|sed 's/^/START/;s/$/END/'
```

So that is fed into the `STDIN` of `scanimage`.